# MFC Accessing lparam throw expection

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have 2 CEdit controlsin the view, both of them have same ID.

In the parent window, i created ON_EN_CHANGE handle to catch their editing message.
Since editing either of those edit box will fire up a message to the handle function, I want to find a way to distinguish which edit control does it come from.

So in my handle function, i used GetCurrentMessage() to obtain the MSG object. and it lparam should be the pointer of calling edit control.

But when i modify it, it returns exception says "access violation reading location"

```
    //onCreate function
    text1->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL, \
    CRect(300,200,400,300), this, 1);
    text2->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL, \
    CRect(100, 100, 300, 200), this, 1);

    //parent class
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CScratchView, CView)
    ...
    ON_EN_CHANGE(1, chandle)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

    //Message handle function
    void CScratchView::chandle()
    {
        const MSG* lst = GetCurrentMessage();
        if (lst->lParam != NULL) {
        CEdit* sa = (CEdit*) lst->lParam;
        sa->SetWindowTextW(_T("what"));
    }
```

Since both edit control share same handle function, i need to know which one is calling. I'm not sure this is the right way to do it. but i think this should work.

Any suggestion would be great. thanks

Comment: You better read [the `EN_CHANGE` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/en-change). The `lParam` "argument" is not a pointer to a `CEdit` control. It's the Windows API *handle* to the control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lParam like this:

```
CEdit *sa = (CEdit *) CWnd::FromHandle(lst->lParam);
```

It would probably be smarter to give the two edit controls different IDs (you use `1` for both).  Then you can inspect `LOWORD(lst->wParam)` which contains the control ID :

```
text1->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL, 
              CRect(300,200,400,300), this, 100);

text2->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL, 
              CRect(100, 100, 300, 200), this, 101);

...

ON_EN_CHANGE(100, chandle)
ON_EN_CHANGE(101, chandle)
```

Also note that `IDOK` is `1`.  Start your control IDs at `100` or higher.

Comment: My edit controls are dynamic generated at runtime. This is just a test code. I'm trying to figure out a way to distinguish them in the handle function. So when one of them is being edited, i would know which one. I try to have them hit the same endpoint and separate from there. Thanks tho. I'll need to test it out.